# Access a Variable Inside a Function

Tags: c#, variables

[enter image description here][1]

How can I have access (e.g. commented Console.WriteLine()) to a variable inside a function?
Tried to declared it in the main function (at the 2 commented positions) but it says it's unused.
Thanks!

```
    public void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     //string filename = “ “;
        try
        {   
            //string filename = “ “;
            rename("02-66977V2", "X");
            //Console.WriteLine(filename);


        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
        }

    }

    public void rename(string Number, string Type)
    {
        string filename = " ";

        try
        {
            if (Number.Contains("V2"))
            {
                filename = Number + Type;
            }
        }

        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't (well you can, but via globals or parameters, not "function to function").  You need to study up on "scope".

Comment: Change `rename` signature to  `public string rename`, and `return filename` in your function `rename`. Your actual question could be "How to I get result of my function".

Comment: Thanks all I will look at the previous questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your actual question is "How to I get result outside of my function".

Change `rename` signature to  `public string rename`, and `return filename` in your function `rename`.

I removed the try catch because you don't need it in this sample.

```
public string rename(string Number, string Type)
{
    string filename = " ";

    if (Number.Contains("V2"))
    {
        filename = Number + Type;
    }
    return filename;
}
```

There are other ways to get return value from a function.
Like [`out`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref).
Or simply return a structure contains multiple values.

Comment: Thanks for the advise.
I did that but this error shows in the rename signature:
'Form1.rename(string, string, string, string, string, string, string, bool)': not all code paths return a value.
In my real codes, rename has more inputs, and there are more if-loops and combinations between the inputs.
And I think I've added return filename; to all ends......

Comment: It's hard to tell, i'd suggest you comment out a block of code to check which one is the problem.

Comment: That's a good suggestion! I think of that too.
But then I read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451454/c-sharp-error-not-all-code-paths-return-a-value
And realized the missing one in catch.
Looks like I really should have spent more time studying C# basics.....

Comment: The hardest thing is finding where to start when you know little. If you want a complete guide, "head first C#" would be a good start.